# spin and "Compile Report' do not convert R script to Rmd in RStudio Preview

Tags: r, rstudio, knitr, r-markdown

I want to use `spin()` function for my R script to produce rmarkdown `.Rmd` file. Instead, RStudio returns `.md` file. This happens in RStudio Preview version 1.1.331.

My R file is from https://github.com/yihui/knitr/blob/master/inst/examples/knitr-spin.R. I downloaded it and put inside my working dir. I then typed `spin("test.R", format = "Rmd")` in the Console pane.

When I clicked enter, in the console, it showed **processing file:knitr-spin.Rmd** then **output file: knitr-spin.md**. Then `knitr-spin.html` and `knitr-spin.md`were visible, but there was no `knitr-spin.Rmd` in the working folder.

For the next try,

1. I clicked the **Compile Report** button
2. I chose `MS Word` outputs

Unfortunately, I still received a folder and an html file and no `.Rmd` file. Not even `.md` file was created.

The last time I used `spin()` or `Compile Report` was inside RStudio  1.0.153 and it worked nicely and I got .Rmd files, html and MS Word files.

What have I done wrong or I missed?

Comment: Have you tried an older version to confirm that it's RStudio?

Comment: tried, and did not work still. .Rmd was created momentarily in the working folder before it disappeared on its own

Answer (score 1):

This should work:
spin("file.R", knit = FALSE)  # convert to Rmd only

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation, argument `spin` appears to be what you're after:

```
precious    
logical: whether intermediate files (e.g., .Rmd files when format is "Rmd") 
         should be preserved; default FALSE if knit == TRUE and input is a file
```

Next to the Knit button there's a sprocket. Click on the Advanced tab and check "Keep markdown source file".

[image]

Comment: it worked. I wish I could get .Rmd too just by clicking 'Compile Report' without using the script.